# Font working for one English but not for Urdu (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, fonts

the font files are working alright, and I installed these fonts when I was designing in figma where the particular font was working in Urdu. But now when I started coding, the font is working for English language but not for Urdu. Please help.

Main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:frontend/widgets/green_button_widget.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'SFPro'),
      home: const Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Text(
          "سائن ان کامیاب",
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 50),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  fonts:
    - family: SFPro
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/SF-Pro-Display-Semibold.otf
        - asset: fonts/SF-Pro-Display-Bold.OTF
        - asset: fonts/SF-Pro-Display-Regular.OTF
        - asset: fonts/SF-Pro-Display-Medium.OTF
```

screenshots of figma font and the font im getting
[Figma][1]

[Flutter][2]

PLS HELP TIA
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mma4A.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/36fR7.jpg